# writing a setter and getter to function pointer in c++

Tags: c++, function-pointers, setter, getter, getter-setter

i have pagePtr class with function pointer which looks like this

```
int (*FunPtr)(char*sz, unsigned int max_bytes, char* arg1, char* arg2, char* arg3,
char* arg4);//Function definition
```

I initialized it in constructor like this

```
pagePtr::pagePtr() : FunPtr(Null)
{
}
```

now i wrote setter something like this i dunno if it is correct

```
void pagePtr::setFunPtr(int(*ptr2Fun)(char*sz, unsigned int max_bytes,
char* arg1, char* arg2, char* arg3, char* arg4))
{
    FunPtr = ptr2Fun;
}
```

i don't have a clue how to write a getter (and setter if what i did was wrong). Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), as it's more flexible than a pure function pointer.

Answer (score 7):

```
typedef int (*FunPtr)(char*sz, unsigned int max_bytes, char* arg1, char* arg2, char* arg3,char* arg4);//Function definition   // magic word!

void pagePtr::setFunPtr(FunPtr func){m_func = func;} //so clean!!!
FunPtr getFunPtr(){return m_func;}
```

Always use `typedef` in such situations to make life a lot easier for everyone..

Define a variable as `FunPtr m_func`.

Comment: thank you for answer, my task was to first figure out how to do without using typedef first, then use typedef and see how easy things get after using typedef. Anyways you solved my next step already. Cheers!!!

Answer (score -1):

For completeness, the actual syntax is

```
int (*pagePtr::getFunPtr())(char*, unsigned int, char*, char*, char*, char*)
{
    return FunPtr;
}
```